# Make .vimrc changes being picked up by Vim only and for me only

Tags: vim, vi

I have a $HOME/.vimrc file which I have configured for many options like below but not limited to.

```
set foldmethod=indent
set foldnestmax=10
set mouse=a
set number
```

These all work fine if I open a file with `vim` however if I open with `vi` or `view` the file none of the config work, which is fine but I get errors for some.

```
line  104:
E538: No mouse support: mouse=a
line  205:
E518: Unknown option: foldmethod=indent
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

After searching quite a while I was able to remove some of these.

```
 if has('mouse')
       set mouse=a
    endif

silent! set foldmethod=indent
```

However this is just suppressing them. And the linenumbers are still being displayed with `vi` or `view` which look pretty bad and many people login to the box will be suddenly mystified by the yellow line numbers.

1. How to make `vi` not take up these config.
2. I powerbroker to the linux box. Can I make .vimrc setting just for me.

Comment: [How to detect vi (not vim) in .vimrc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636721/how-to-detect-vi-not-vim-in-vimrc) tells you the difference between a real `vi` (i.e. old version) and modern `vim`.

Comment: @Amadan  `:if version >= 500` solution in the above answer worked. but when I do `vi --version`, it shows `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Feb 17 2012 10:24:10)` so it's a VIM compiled vi with features off. As I can see further in description `Small version without GUI`. But why this worked? Am I missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vi` and `vim` are the same executable.

I'd suggest you change the name of your `vimrc`:

```
$ mv ~/.vimrc ~/.myvimrc
```

and start Vim with:

```
$ vim -Nu ~/.myvimrc
```

You could add an alias to `~/.bashrc` (or whatever works in that system) to ease your workflow:

```
alias myvim='/usr/bin/vim -Nu ~/.myvimrc'
```

Comment: but wouldn't changing .bashrc will make changes to bash of everybody and it will be the same then.

Comment: No, because you add *your* own alias. Other people will simply use `vi` or `vim` as usual (with the default settings) while *you* will use `myvim`, which will source *your* `vimrc`.

Answer (score 1):

As `vi` does not support all options of `vim`, What I do is to set alias for vi to vim in my rc file

```
alias vim='vim -p'
alias vi='vim -p'
```

The `-p` is not really required. but I kinda like `tabbing` enabled by default on `vim`. So every time, if you hit `vi` or `vim`, it behaves the same.

You can make this permanent, if you like, by adding the lines to `~/.bashrc`, assuming you are using `bash`. You need to `source ~/.bashrc` to take immediate effect without logging off.